# Spring @Valid annotation

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

I have form:

```
<form:form id="my-registration-form" method="post" commandName="userDTO" modelAttribute="userDTO" action="/index/register.do">
        <p class="error">
            <form:errors path="*" cssClass="errorblock" element="div" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <form:input path="username" />
            <form:errors path="username" cssClass="error" />
            <%--<input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" value="">--%>
        </p>
        <p>
            <form:input path="email" />
            <form:errors path="email" cssClass="error" />
            <%--<input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" value="">--%>
        </p>
        <p class="submit">
            <input type="submit" class="button" value="Register">
        </p>
    </form:form>
```

Action = /index/register.do

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/register.do", headers = "Accept=application/json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String registerUser(@Valid UserDTO userDTO, HttpServletRequest request,
                           BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes attributes) {

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "error"
    }
}
```

And my model UserDTO:

```
    public class UserDTO {

        private String uuid;

        @NotEmpty(message = "This field req")
        @Length(min = 6, max = 30, message = "6 or 30")
        protected String username;

        protected String password;

        @NotEmpty(message = "Email required")
        @Email(message = "Enter good email")
        protected String email;
    }
```

So my problem is: when i left @NotEmpty annotation - and on page i press submit button with empty inputs - everything is okay, my controller method registerUser invoked, see errors and works properly. But when i add @Email, @Size, @Length, @Range, @Min, @Max annotations (any of them) in UserDTO class on any field and for a example i fill username and email inputs on page using one symbol (Size, Length, Min annotations have to validate count of symbols in input) and press submit button - in debug log i see that bindingresult contains errors, but my controller method registerUser did not invoke - instead of this i got HttpError 502 BadGateway and blank page - method of my controller did not invoke.

What's wrong?

**UPDATE:**
I did not have 502 BadGateway indeed, i have an Exception in Controller, because FieldErrors at Length annotation.

Comment: If you use a form, why in your controller method do you have `headers = "Accept=application/json"`, why don't you have a `@ModelAttribute` before `UserDto userDto` ?  And the BindingResul param should be immediately after it, and not after the request param.

Comment: First of, i can do not use `@ModelAttribute` if i use `@Valid`. Then, post as answer that `BindingResult` must be immediately after `@Valid`, not after request param - that's the answer! Everything works! Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is explicit in Spring Reference Manual, in a `RequestMapping` annotated method of a MVC controller, a `BindingResult` parameter must immediately follow the parameter it refers.

In your case you should write :

```
public String registerUser(@Valid UserDTO userDTO, BindingResult result,
           HttpServletRequest request, RedirectAttributes attributes) {
```

Answer (score 1):

The **BindingResult result** method parameter must immediate follow the form bean in the method parameter list.